# ¿Como configuro esta extension de VS code?

Tags: json, visual-studio

Descargue la extension **Bracket Pair Colorizer** y la estoy configurando, la parte que quiero configurar es esta, [segun la documentacion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer):

> "bracketPairColorizer.activeScopeCSS" Choose a border style to
>   highlight the active scope. Use {color} to match the existing bracket
>   color It is recommended to disable the inbuilt editor.matchBrackets
>   setting if using this feature
>   Tip: Add the value "backgroundColor : {color}" to increase visibility

Entonces le di a la rueda de configuración de extensiones que ofrece VSCode busque el archivo a modificar y me mando para su JSON pero no se donde colocar esa linea de código, este es el JSON:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro (Filter Machine)",
    "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "${extensionPath}/php-cs-fixer.phar",
    "php-cs-fixer.lastDownload": 1571337092925,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "mohd-akram.vscode-html-format",

    },
    "editor.matchBrackets": false
}
```

Comment: Que versión de **VSCode** tienes ? esta extencion solo la tienes que habilitar y reiniciar **VSCode** y ya queda funcionando, Elimina la extencion la instalas de nuevo y le das habilitar, recargar **VSCode** y creo que te funcionara, pero mejor descarga la **version 2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta para llegar hasta donde quieres.. tu JSON es la siguiente...

1. File>Preferences>Extensions(control+shift+x)
2. Buscas tu extension Bracket Pair Colorizer.
3. Click en el icono de configuracion(engranaje) a la izquierda.Configure extension settings.
4. Buscas la opcion => Bracket Pair Colorizer: Active Scope CSS.
5. Edit in settings.json

Tambien puedes hacer..

1. **Control + ,**
2. En el input superior pones: @ext:coenraads.bracket-pair-colorizer

Yo estoy viendo ahora el settings.json y su contenido es distinto a lo que quieres insertar pero si estas viendo alguna documentación y te dice de introducir este código es ahí donde debes ponerlo... Por lo demás yo la uso y como te decían en los comentarios lo único que hice fue instalarla..